# How to transform a column using a for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, transformation

I am trying to transform Amazon product names into specific categories and replace the original values in my data frame. How do I do this?

I already have a regex code and for loop that is able to find and print the transformation, but I am having trouble replacing the original values in the column. I also have a nested for loop that seems to work, but it only transforms and replaces one of the categories (Kindle) correctly. I'm thinking my break conditions aren't working as I would like.

Code to define Categories:

```r
fire = unique(grep('^[^Certified].*Fire TV', amz$name, value=TRUE))
kindle = unique(grep('^[^Certified]*Kindle', amz$name, value=TRUE))
echo = unique(grep('[^Certified].*Echo', amz$name, value=TRUE))
tap = unique(grep('[^Certified].*Tap', amz$name, value=TRUE))
tablet = unique(grep('^[^Certified].*Tablet', amz$name, value=TRUE))
refurb = unique(grep('^Certified', amz$name, value=TRUE))
```

Code to transform and print Categories:

```r
for (x in amz$name){
        if(x %in% fire
        ){print('Fire TV')} else if(x %in% kindle
        ){print('Kindle')} else if(x %in% echo
        ){print('Echo')} else if(x %in% tap
        ){print('Tap')} else if(x %in% tablet
        ){print('Tablet')} else if(x %in% refurb
        ){print('Certified Refurbished')} else {
                                print('Misc')
                            }
                        }
```

Code attempting to replace original values:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(amz)){
    for (x in amz$name[i]){
        if(x %in% fire
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Fire TV') 
                break} else if(x %in% kindle
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Kindle') 
                break} else if(x %in% echo
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Echo') 
                break} else if(x %in% tap
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Tap') 
                break} else if(x %in% tablet
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Tablet') 
                break} else if(x %in% refurb
            ){(amz$name[i] <- 'Certified Refurbished') 
                break} else {(amz$name[i] <- 'Misc') 
                    break
        }
    }
}
```

In the inner loop, I expect that the code checks if x is in the first list, and if not, then it moves to the next one until it finds the list it belongs to and enters the category in amz$name[i]. Once it is found and inputted, I want the inner loop to break, and the outer loop to move to the second iteration, i=2. So far it is only getting it correct for the first category, the rest of the categories return NA. I should say that product at amz$name[1] is a Kindle Paperwhite. So it seems to be selectively categorizing Kindle products.

Comment: Take a look at the `dplyr` package, specifically the `mutate` and `case_when` functions. The big advantage of R is vectorized calculations, which you lose when you use nested for loops

Comment: Thanks @divibisan, will take a look at that. I definitely know there are more computationally efficient ways to do this but I'm still getting a grasp of R. Appreciate the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the data is in a data frame, then you can check the ifelse statement.

Do note, you have to use multiple ifelse statements, but it is vectorized and will run faster compared to for loop for larger data sets.

```
ifelse(x %in% 'fire', "Fire TV", ifelse(x %in% 'Kindle', "Kindle", ifelse(x %in% 'alex', "Alexa", "Misc")))
```

The above is written for 3 cases, you can adjust accordingly for more cases...
One example below...

```
> x="alex"
> ifelse(x %in% 'fire', "Fire TV", ifelse(x %in% 'Kindle', "Kindle", ifelse(x %in% 'alex', "Alexa", "Misc")))
[1] "Alexa"
> x="mango"
> ifelse(x %in% 'fire', "Fire TV", ifelse(x %in% 'Kindle', "Kindle", ifelse(x %in% 'alex', "Alexa", "Misc")))
[1] "Misc"
> x=rbind("alex","mango")
> ifelse(x %in% 'fire', "Fire TV", ifelse(x %in% 'Kindle', "Kindle", ifelse(x %in% 'alex', "Alexa", "Misc")))
[1] "Alexa" "Misc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @divibisan and @FlyingPickle! Using both mutate and ifelse, I was able to arrive to a solution for my problem.

```r
amz <- mutate(amz, newCat = 
    ifelse(name %in% fire,
    'Amazon Fire TV', 
            ifelse(name %in% kindle,
            'Amazon Kindle',
                ifelse(name %in% echo,
                'Amazon Echo',
                    ifelse(name %in% tap,
                    'Amazon Tap',
                        ifelse(name %in% tablet,
                        'Amazon Tablet',
                            ifelse(name %in% refurb,
                            'Certified Refurbished',
                            'Misc.'

                )))))))
```